# why neuron network's parameter space has a Riemann metric structure?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

In the [natural gradient paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/1996/file/39e4973ba3321b80f37d9b55f63ed8b8-Paper.pdf), the first line writes:

> The parameter space of neural networks has a Riemannian metric structure.

I don't know why. I has basic knowledge of Riemannian metric: it defines the metric of local space of riemanian space. And I know riemannian space is a curved space. But I don't get it that how is the NN parameter space a curved space rather the Euclidean space?

---

I have read [the correspoonding material](https://file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/1215467059.pdf) mentioned in the paper briefly, it seems to *regard NN as a probability density functions which is in L1 space, suggesting that the parameter space is constrained to make the function be in L1.* I am fine with the explaination. But as I know, *the parameters of a network is not necessarily under some constraint. And I doubt NN is a L1 function because usually we just apply softmax layer to the raw output of the NN to make the output within (0,1).*

Comment: The first paragraph of the paper mentions that this is introduced in Amari (1985). Have you checked there?

Comment: @Arkady Thanks for the hint. I have read the material briefly, it seems to regard NN as a probability density functions which is in L1 space, suggesting that the parameter space is constrained to make the function be in L1. I am fine with the explaination. But as i know, the parameters of a network is not necessarily under some constraint. And I doubt NN is a L1 function because usually we just apply softmax layer to the raw output of the NN.